# Cannot connect my client and server app made with Qt netwoking

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

I made a project in c++. The project is complete. I used Qt networking for that, to send message between serer and client application.In same pc both can send and recieve message , but in communication in different pc doesnt work. If I open the client in another pc and server in mine it wont connect.

I tried specifying the serverIp. I tested it again in same pc , when the ip is wrong it won't connect even in same pc, but when corrected , it connects. Checked if the firewall is the issue , did every method for firewall. I am seeing a potential problem that it mightnot be connecting via internet at all. I am new to this netwoking and just geting started. Here is the github link for the project: 
also here is the client and server side code that manages connection:

```
//clientManager.h
#ifndef CLIENTMANAGER_H
#define CLIENTMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
class ClientManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClientManager(QString ip = "Server IP here", ushort port = 4500, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void connectToServer();
    void sendMessage(QString message);
    void disconnectFromServer();
signals:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void dataReceived(QByteArray data);
private slots:
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket *_socket;
    QString _ip;
    ushort _port;
};

#endif // CLIENTMANAGER_H
```

```
//clientManager.cpp
#include "ClientManager.h"

ClientManager::ClientManager(QString ip,ushort port,QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent},
    _ip(ip),
    _port(port)
{
    _socket= new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(_socket,&QTcpSocket::connected,this,&ClientManager::connected);
    connect(_socket,&QTcpSocket::disconnected,this,&ClientManager::disconnected);
    connect(_socket,&QTcpSocket::readyRead,this,&ClientManager::readyRead);
}

void ClientManager::connectToServer()
{
    _socket->connectToHost(_ip,_port);
}

void ClientManager::sendMessage(QString message)
{
    _socket->write(message.toUtf8());
}
void ClientManager::readyRead()
{
    auto data = _socket->readAll();
    emit dataReceived(data);
}
void ClientManager::disconnectFromServer()
{
    _socket->disconnectFromHost();
}
```

the server side:

```
//servermanager.h
#ifndef SERVERMANAGER_H
#define SERVERMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include<QTcpServer>

class ServerManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ServerManager(ushort port=4500,QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void disconnectAllClients();
private slots:
    void newClientConnectionRecieved();
    void onClientDisconnected();
signals:
    void newClientConnected(QTcpSocket *client);
    void clientDisconnected(QTcpSocket *client);
private://field
    QTcpServer *_server;
    QList<QTcpSocket *> _clients;
private://methods
     void setupServer(ushort port);
};

#endif
```

```
//servermanager.cpp
#include "ServerManager.h"
#include "qtcpsocket.h"
ServerManager::ServerManager(ushort port,QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    setupServer(port);
}
void ServerManager::newClientConnectionRecieved()
{
    auto client = _server->nextPendingConnection();
    _clients << client;
    auto id = _clients.length();
    client->setProperty("id",id);
    connect(client, &QTcpSocket::disconnected,this,&ServerManager::onClientDisconnected);
    emit newClientConnected(client);
}
void ServerManager::onClientDisconnected()
{
    auto client = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket *>(sender());
 //   int id = client->property("id").toInt();
    _clients.removeOne(client);
    emit clientDisconnected(client);
}
void ServerManager::setupServer(ushort port)
{
    _server=new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(_server, &QTcpServer::newConnection,this,&ServerManager::newClientConnectionRecieved);
    _server->listen(QHostAddress::Any,port);
}
void ServerManager::disconnectAllClients()//for disconnecting all client
{
    for (QTcpSocket* client : qAsConst(_clients)) {//looks for every active client and disconnects
        client->disconnectFromHost();
    }
}
```